# Tool to quickly install javascript libraries from the web

Tags: javascript, macos

Is there something like brew for mac to install javascript libraries in the current folder?
Like this:

```
jsbrew install jquery
jsbrew install angularjs
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try Node.js with Bower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Bower. It's package manager for front-end libraries: http://bower.io/

Comment: It's strange that I had to wait 2 months to get this answer that I am sure is obvious for those who knows about this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I was also surprised :)